# Repackaging with Spring-boot-gradle-plugin v2.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

The spring-boot-maven-plugin has a goal that allows you to repackage an existing jar. This helped me in repackaging my obfuscated jar:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.14</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <proguardVersion>6.1.1</proguardVersion>
                <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
                <outjar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</outjar>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <proguardInclude>${basedir}/config.pro</proguardInclude>
                <libs>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
                </libs>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                    <version>6.1.1</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <!--Repackaging using the spring-boot-maven-plugin-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>com.afferentsoftware</groupId>
                        <artifactId>securemessageprocessor</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>com.afferentsoftware</groupId>
                        <artifactId>messagelibmodule</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

However, I have recently migrated from Maven to Gradle (v5.4) and have been using the spring-boot-gradle-plugin:

```
plugin
{
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.8.RELEASE'
   id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
}
```

I know that the bootJar task is now responsible to create the spring boot jar. However I have been unable use it to repackage my obfuscated jar.

How can I do that in Gradle with the Spring-boot-gradle-plugin?